# PHP memcached - php_msgpack_serialize in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, memcached

Recently upgraded PHP and ran into the following error message while updating:

`php_msgpack_serialize in Unknown on line 0`

So first of all, never heard of this package.  All searches for this package leads to a single PECL repo (which really doesn't mean anything either) - which has about zero mentions from the community.

A few more searches and I tracked the origin down to a repo for [php-memcached-dev](https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/blob/master/php_memcached.c)  - a repository I've never seen or heard of.

Of course, I *have* heard of the actual memcached library repo: [libmemcached](https://github.com/kajidai/php-libmemcached/tree/master)

I tried looking for this module everywhere for a sign of it being a legit part of centos but i can't seem to get any good/reliable results.

Places I searched for any sign of this package and/or repository:

- http://pkgs.org/
- http://stackoverflow.com
- http://php.net
- http://centos.org
- Just searched https://bugs.php.net too...

I don't want to seem paranoid here, but I'm not even sure if this is legit at this stage.

Shrug - I dunno.  I'm keeping my server turned off though until I see something else.  Anyone have some advice/input ?

For the paranoid (and yes, I found it from being a little bit myself), here is an ugly google search : [php_msgpack backdoor](https://www.google.com/search?q=undefined+symbol%3A+php_msgpack_serialize+in+Unknown+on+line+0&oq=undefined+symbol%3A+php_msgpack_serialize+in+Unknown+on+line+0&aqs=chrome..69i57.313j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#q=php_msgpack+backdoor)  (note: only has <s>2</s> **3** search results.  Check out the date in  the <s>2nd</s> **3rd**.  i haven't clicked it myself and would not recommend anyone else click it either)  This seems to be a rkhunter search looking for the same file being reported above.  Probably just a coincidence but who knows.  Thought I'd push it out there anyways.

UPDATE:  Well, long story short this turned out to be an issue with a version of PHP that was installed with Cent.  It has been fixed with the latest version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Ubunu 16.04 with PHP 5.5 from the Ondrej-PPA (https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) I could solve the problem by installing the package php-msgpack:

`sudo apt-get install php-msgpack`

And than enabling the php-msgpack with

`sudo phpenmod msgpack`

Perhaps you ave to restart apache2 after that if you use it with PHP.

Than this error is gone:

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20121212/memcached.so' - /usr/lib/php/20121212/memcached.so: undefined symbol: php_msgpack_serialize in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: Oh God.  This worked.  Please explain why this works!?

Comment: Because the missing file comes with this library.

Comment: Its unreal to me (but very common to php in my experience) that they would release a package (memcached) without including an external dependency.  It seems like bad practice to release a library and not include all the required files it needs to run.  No it doesn't seem like bad practice, it IS bad practice.

Comment: I had this same problem too on MAMP (pro), just enable the msgpack.so extension too and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 4):

One last thing to check:
**msgpack extension must be loaded before memcached.**

In my scenario extensions were loaded alphabetically and therefore memcached was loaded before msgpack. Php cli didn't work until I loaded msgpack before memcached.

Comment: Same for me. Had to modify `/etc/php/<version>/mods-available/msgpack.ini` to change in it : `priority=20` to `priority=15`.  Then `phpdismod msgpack` and `phpenmod msgpack`

Answer (score 2):

Following commands solved my issue.

`sudo apt-get install php-igbinary`

`sudo apt-get install php-msgpack`

`sudo service php7.3-fpm reload  #Change to your version`

Reference:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/forge/php-71-update-broken-memcached

Answer (score 2):

If you land here in Oct 2020 because you're getting an error after upgrading and you're using the repository **ppa:ondrej/php** you need to install the specific version of msgpack because *all-of-a-sudden* memcached is looking for this shared object.

We're running php 7.3 from this repo and although php-msgpack was installed, we needed to install **php7.3-msgpack** (which wasn't needed until this upgrade). No need to "enable" it as mentioned in the accepted answer. Just restart php.

Two steps:

```
sudo apt install php7.3-msgpack
sudo systemctl restart php7.3-fpm.service
```

Answer (score 0):

- http://msgpack.org/
- http://pecl.php.net/package/msgpack
- https://code.google.com/p/php-msgpack/

If your codebase doesn't use MsgPack, you can remove it from the php.ini and/or smaller files that mention it in the php.d/* subdirectories.

Comment: That's cool - I think I was just wondering more of if this was a known package in centos - to satisfy my curiosity.  has msgpack always been in php.ini?  i don't think i ever noticed it before

Answer (score 0):

Well, long story short this turned out to be an issue with a version of PHP that was installed with Cent.  It has been fixed with the latest version.